# Picking the latest file from a folder

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, centos

I have a couple of files in a folder such as `abc_2-01-2019.csv`, `abc_2-02-2019.csv`, `abc_2-03-2019.csv`, `abc_2-04-2019.csv`, and I want to pick the latest file and send it over an email as an attachment on Linux VM. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: `latest file` - according to creation date? modification date?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

where

```
 -A  do not include . and ..
 -t sort by modification time
 -r reverse sort
```

and `tail -n 1` gets last entry

Comment: but that folder also contains other files than required CSVs. I want to choose latest csv with name abc_latest_date.csv